# UITextField inside a custom UITableViewCell not becoming first responder correctly when switching between text fields

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCells` that have `UITextFields` inside them.

When I tap on the first one, it becomes the first responder – the keyboard pops up, and the cursor shows up. When I tap on another text field, sometimes it works, but sometimes the cursor disappears and whatever I type with the keyboard is not going anywhere. Again, this only happens *sometimes*, in both the simulator and hardware iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I had an `EditingDidEnd` action connected to these text fields which made the `UITableViewController` make a `reloadData` call.

Once that call was removed everything worked as expected.